# j2me: using custom fonts(bitmap) performance

Tags: java-me, fonts

I want to use custom fonts in my j2me application. so I created a png file contains all needed glyph and an array of glyphs width and another for glyphs offset in PNG file.

Now, I want to render a text in my app using above font within a gameCanvas class. but when I use the following code, rendering text in real device is very slow.

Note: the text is coded(for some purposes) to bytes and stored in this.text variable. 242=[space],241=[\n] and 243=[\r].

```
int textIndex = 0;
while(textIndex < this.text.length)
{
  int index = this.text[textIndex] & 0xFF;
  if(index > 243)
  {
      continue;
  }
  else if(index == 242) lineLeft += 3;
  else if(index == 241 || index == 243) 
  {
      top += font.getHeight();
      lineLeft = 0;
      continue;
  }
  else
  {
    lineLeft += widths[index];
    if(lineLeft <= getWidth()) 
        lineLeft = 0;
    int left = starts[index];
    int charWidth = widths[index];
    try{
        bg.drawRegion(font, left, 0, charWidth, font.getHeight(), 0, lineLeft, top, Graphics.LEFT|Graphics.TOP);
    }catch(Exception ee)
    {
    }
  }
  textIndex++;
}
```

Can anyone help me to improve performance and speed in my code?

At end sorry for my bad English and thanks in advanced.:)

Edit: I changed line

```
 bg.drawRegion(font, left, 0, charWidth, font.getHeight(), 0, lineLeft, top, Graphics.LEFT|Graphics.TOP);
```

To:

```
bg.clipRect(left, top, charWidth, font.getHeight());
bg.drawImage(font, lineLeft - left, top,0)
bg.setClip(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

but there was no difference in speed!!

any help please!!

---

Can anyone plz help me to improve my app?

text will appear after 2-3 seconds in real device by this code, I want reduce this time to milliseconds. this is very important for me.

Can I use threads? If yes, How?

Comment: Maybe, your problem relates with double buffering? Did you try to flush canvas or game canvas after drawing font? Did you check the performance of this function by using counter? or, just checking it with your eyes?

Comment: First I created an image of size of screen.then i got graphics from that image (Graphics bg = bufferImage.getGraphics();) and draw glyphs to that image. and then in paint() method i paint only bufferImage.(sorry for bad English!!)

Comment: I checked performance with my eyes!!!. it takes a lot time to completes drawing glyphs to bufferImage.

Comment: I recommend to check performance with counter (time). How about test your functions with time measurement if it really takes 2 seconds to run. And, if not there should be other reason of slow performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't sure why your code's performance is not good in real device.
But, how about refer some well known open source J2ME libraries to check it's text drawing implementation for example, LWUIT.

http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/content/LWUIT_1_5/UI/src/com/sun/lwuit/CustomFont.java?rev=1628

You can find from the above link it's font drawing implementation. It uses drawImage rather than drawRegion.

Comment: thanks,I will see the above link and will report the results some hours later.

Comment: edited my question by getting idea from lwuit source code. but no diffrence.(I can't use lwuit library, I have to use my own method for text rendering.)

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to look into [this](http://www.xiteapplet.de/) library. The implementation is quite good and makes use of industry standard design patters ( Flyweight pattern, predominantly) and robust.

Comment: Thanks, I tested that library. but it is very heavy too. and it don't support RTL languages.